# Error when compare a current text with the data store inside my database

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my code, I'm failed to compare my data. I'm new in C#.

```
protected void Button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\registerdatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from [taccompare]";
        cmd.Connection = con;

        SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            if (rd[1].ToString() == TextBox1.Text)
            {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag == true)
            Label1.Text = "correct";
        else
            Label1.Text = "wrong";

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
    }

}
```

Here is my database table

[image]

For my purpose, I'm going to get all the value in column [currentotp] and it fail to get does data and compare with the value that user type Textbox1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints:

1. You could use column names as index when getting data from data reader
   Example: `rd["currentotp"]`. Then you are sure to read the right column.
2. When reading data from database: Check for null values. "currentotp" in the first row of your screenshot is null.(Example: `if (rd["currentotp"] != null && rd["currentotp"].ToString() == TextBox1.Text)` )
3. If you write column names in your select statement, it is easier to check columns and find typos. Example: `"select username, date, currentotp, time from [taccompare]"`